# multiple similar applications in a single database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

i'm using codeigniter.
i'm limited to 1 mysql database.

if i have a web application with many tables for use on 1 company.
i would access it like:

http://www.abc.com/login

http://www.abc.com/member/sales.php

if i want to use the same application for other companies in the same database, how should i proceed? and how can i access it using codeigniter?
i can't seems to figure it out.
many thanks for your guidance.

Comment: Are you limited to one database or to one schema? I.e, can you run "create schema <name>" to create new schemas?

Comment: dear andreas,
sorry i do not understand "schema". if my database name is "xxx", then all my tables are in this "xxx" folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create a table names with the prefix of the Company name that will give the clarity of the table names also...In the code u can easily identify the Name with the prefix.

Comment: does this means i have to store this variable(table prefix) in session so that i need to access it from time to time?

Comment: beside this method, is there other methods?

Answer (score 0):

I guess in your case codeignitor is mere a development framework not more than that so try to create a seperate table with name of companies and use PID of company table for identify all the records related to the company.

Or if creating schemas is not an issue than codeignitor provides you facility to connect more than one database at a time, please go through following link -

["Connecting to Multiple Databases"](http://www.codeignitor.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html)